# Unsure of definition of composite functions and integrals

Tags: calculus, functions

Could someone explain to me what this function represents and how it is  possible.

> Lets have $y :\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}^2 $ and that $f: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, and lets assume that ${f(y(x))}$ is given and that $y(x) = y(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^xf(y(t))dt$

But I'm a bit confused how there can be a function of $y(t)$ inside of the function definition for $y(x)$.

I took the example that $y(x) = (x^2, x)$ and $f(y,z) = (y+z, y-z)$.

$$
\Rightarrow f(y(x)) = f(x^2,x) = (x^2+x,x^2-x)
$$

And now if we follow the definition of $y(x)$ we get:
$$
y(x) = y(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^xf(y(t))dt
$$
$$
y(x) = y(x_0) + \int_{x_0}^x(t^2+t,t^2-t)dt
$$ 
$$\Rightarrow y(x) = y(x_0) + (\frac{1}{3}t^3 + \frac{1}{2}t^2,\frac{1}{3}t^3 -\frac{1}{2}t^2)\Big|_{x_0}^x$$
$$
\Rightarrow y(x) =(\frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C_1,\frac{1}{3}x^3 -\frac{1}{2}x^2+C_2) 
$$

But from the top I have defined that $y(x) = (x^2, x)$, and now I get the above equation after integration, but clearly they are not the same functions. Have I misunderstood the definition of the functions, or made a mistake in my calculations? Or have I chosen the wrong functions for my example?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What the original statement was saying is that the value of the function $y$ at $x$ is dependent on the value of that function at $[x_0,x)$ (modulo a set of measure zero perhaps).  Do you see why this is the case?

Comment: Hi fixedp, sorry I'm still unsure of what you are saying, could you give simple example? The definition is still difficult to understand, Thanks

Comment: There seems to be part of the question missing in the original statement. Is giving such an example part of your homework? If yes, I will provide only hints. I can also type out in more detail what I meant in my original comment.

Comment: This is the definition of the functions for a question. We are suppose to find the derivatives $y',y'', y'''$, using the chain rule, I have some answers. I was just wanting to test some functions to see if my derivatives are correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the simplest example is to fix $f(x,y)=(x+1,y+1)$ and let $y(x)=(e^x-1,e^x-1)$.

Comment: Haha yes it works! Thanks alot fixedp, cheers!